# Installing generic-logos and generic-release on Fedora

Tags: fedora, yum, virtual-machine, packaging, distributions

The [guidelines for Fedora remixes](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Remix) suggest to replaces packages `fedora-logos`, `fedora-release`, and `fedora-release-notes` with the `generic-*` equivalents when making a remix. Most tutorials online focus on creating a live-cd remix; I'm interesting in creating a VM, without making a live CD first.

I tried the following:

- `yum install generic-logos generic-release generic-release-notes`: the `generic-*` packages conflicts with the `fedora-*` packages, preventing installation.
- `yum erase fedora-logos fedora-release fedora-release-notes`: this removes about 200MB of dependencies, most of which I want to keep.
- `rpm -e --no-deps fedora-logos fedora-release fedora-release-notes`: this completes successfully, but unsets the `$releasever` variable that yum uses, causing it to complain when I try to run `yum install generic-release`

  > Could not parse metalink https://mirrors.fedora.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever/&arch=x86_64 error was
  >   No repomd file

How can I replace the `fedora-logos`, `fedora-release` and `fedora-release-notes` packages with their generic equivalents in a VM, without creating a live CD first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
# yum shell
> remove fedora-logos fedora-release fedora-release-notes
> install generic-logos generic-release generic-release-notes
> run
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fedora-logos.x86_64 0:21.0.5-1.fc21 will be erased
---> Package fedora-release.noarch 0:21-2 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: fedora-release = 21-2 for package: fedora-release-nonproduct-21-2.noarch
---> Package fedora-release-notes.noarch 0:21.08-1.fc21 will be erased
---> Package generic-logos.noarch 0:17.0.0-6.fc21 will be installed
---> Package generic-release.noarch 0:21-7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: system-release-product for package: generic-release-21-7.noarch
---> Package generic-release-notes.noarch 0:21-7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fedora-release-nonproduct.noarch 0:21-2 will be erased
---> Package generic-release-cloud.noarch 0:21-7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

==============================================================================
 Package                      Arch      Version            Repository    Size
==============================================================================
Installing:
 generic-logos                noarch    17.0.0-6.fc21      fedora       615 k
 generic-release              noarch    21-7               fedora        14 k
 generic-release-notes        noarch    21-7               fedora        12 k
Removing:
 fedora-logos                 x86_64    21.0.5-1.fc21      installed    8.8 M
 fedora-release               noarch    21-2               installed    4.1 k
 fedora-release-notes         noarch    21.08-1.fc21       installed    603 k
Installing for dependencies:
 generic-release-cloud        noarch    21-7               fedora        12 k
Removing for dependencies:
 fedora-release-nonproduct    noarch    21-2               installed    1.0 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================
Install  3 Packages (+1 Dependent package)
Remove   3 Packages (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 653 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

Or maybe downloading these *generic...* packages and after `rpm -e --no-deps fedora-logos fedora-release fedora-release-notes` you have mentioned installing them via rpm again - something like this: `rpm -ivh generic-*`. After this you probably want to check all is fine with `package-cleanup --problems` (utility from *yum-utils* package).